# Linking External C++ Library (Exerces) in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

**I am working on a C++ project with**

```
#include <xercesc/sax2/ContentHandler.hpp>
#include <xercesc/sax2/Attributes.hpp>
#include <xercesc/util/XMLString.hpp>
```

**On the offical xercesc website, they have the following instructions:**
[image]

- **I downloaded the distribution file**
- **Opened the xerces-all.sln file in VS2017 and pressed build**
- **Then I opened my project in VS2017, went to `properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies` and added xerces-c.lib**

***However the VS2017 complier still can not find the included xerces files***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The included documention you are looking at is titled "Building on Windows" so if for beuiding the library, not on using it afterwards.

You need to add the path to the include files in your project in C/C++ -> General ->Additional include directories

And for the library, you may need to add to the Additional Library Directories

Comment: I added path to xersec source file to Additional include directories, it still doesn't work